# Dependency Scanning not triggering in GitLab CICD pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd, devsecops

I am new to GitLab and was trying to build a sample CICD pipeline. Following is my code:

```
variables:
    REPO_NAME: devsecopscollab/my_test_repo
    IMAGE_TAG: demo-app-1.0

include:
    - template: SAST.gitlab-ci.yml
    - template: Dependency-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml

stages:
    - Test
    - Build
    - Deploy

job1_runTests:
    stage: Test
    image: python:3.10.8
    before_script:
        - apt-get update && apt-get install make
    script:
        - make test

sast:
    stage: Test
    artifacts:
        name: sast
        paths:
            - gl-sast-report.json
        reports:
            sast: gl-sast-report.json
        when: always

dependency_scanning:
    stage: Test
    variables:
        CI_DEBUG_TRACE: "true"
    artifacts:
        name: dependency_scanning
        paths:
            - gl-dependency-scanning-report.json
        reports:
            dependency_scanning: gl-dependency-scanning-report.json
        when: always

job2_buildImage:
    stage: Build
    image: docker:20.10.21
    services:
        - docker:20.10.21-dind
    variables:
        DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
    before_script:
        - docker login -u $DOCKERHUB_USER -p $DOCKERHUB_PASS
    script:
        - docker build -t $REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG .
        - docker push $REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG

job3_deploy:
    stage: Deploy
    before_script:
        - chmod 400 $SSH_KEY 
    script:
        - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $SSH_KEY ubuntu@$PUBLIC_IP "
            docker login -u $DOCKERHUB_USER -p $DOCKERHUB_PASS &&
            docker ps -aq | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker stop | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rm &&
            docker run -d -p 5000:5000 $REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG"
```

But my pipeline looks like in this image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDLBQ.png) (no dependency scanning stage is shown):

Is something wrong with this pipeline? Why is dependency scanning stage not visible?

Tried the above given code snippet and was expecting a dependency scanning stage visible on the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency scanning works only in ultimate plan. cf: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/327366
https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7GE9.png
Also check this link https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/dependency_scanning/
to trigger the dependency scanning template is easer just use

```
include:
 - template: SAST.gitlab-ci.yml
 - template: Dependency-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do not have an Ultimate plan yet. Let me see if I can get a trial one and check with that. But thanks again for letting me know.